# response.body.getReader is not a function

Tags: typescript, node-fetch

I'm making a call to a web api using fetch. I want to read the response as a stream however when I call getReader() on response.body I get the error: "TypeError: response.body.getReader is not a function".

```
  const fetch = require("node-fetch");
  let response = await fetch(url);
  let reader = response.body.getReader();
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a difference between the javascript implementation of `fetch` and the one of node `node-fetch`.

You can try the following:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.body)
    .then(res => res.on('readable', () => {
    let chunk;
    while (null !== (chunk = res.read())) {
        console.log(chunk.toString());
    }
}))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The body returns a Node native readable stream, which you can read using the conveniently named `read()` method.

You can find more about the differences under [here](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/blob/HEAD/LIMITS.md). More specifically:

For convenience, `res.body` is a `Node.js` Readable stream, so decoding can be handled independently.

Hope it helps !